# Background turns green after rendering green tile in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, draw, lwjgl

Hi I am new to LWJGL and I need help with drawing items on the screen. I have a problem when I render my 2D tiles my background's colour is changed to the one the tile is coloured with. So for example if I make a green tile the background goes green too! Here is my code:

MainClass:

```
    public class Mian {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480));
        Display.create();

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

            setCamera();
            drawBackground();
            createLevel();
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);

        }
        Display.destroy();

    }

    public static void setCamera() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 640, 0, 480, -1, 1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public static void drawBackground(){
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glColor3d(0.6, 0.7, 1);
        glVertex2d(0, 0);
        glVertex2d(640, 0);

        glColor3d(0.3, 0.5, 1);
        glVertex2d(640, 480);
        glVertex2d(0, 480);

        glEnd();
    }

    public static void createLevel(){
        List<Tile> tileList = new ArrayList<Tile>();
        tileList.add(new Tile(0,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(32,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(64,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(96,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(128,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(160,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(192,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(224,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(256,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(288,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(320,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(352,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(384,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(416,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(448,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(480,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(512,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(544,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(576,0,"res/GrassTile"));
        tileList.add(new Tile(608,0,"res/GrassTile"));


    }

}
```

Tile Class:

```
package Entitites;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

public class Tile {
    public static int x;
    public static int y;
    public static Texture texture;

    public Tile(int tileX, int tileY, String path) {
        x = tileX;
        y = tileY;
        try {
            texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",
                    ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path + ".png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error loading a tile texture! X:" + x + " - Y:"
                    + y);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        drawTile();
    }

    public static void drawTile() {

        Color.white.bind();
        texture.bind();

        GL11.glPushMatrix();
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glTranslated(x, y, 0);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(1 + texture.getTextureWidth(), 0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(1 + texture.getTextureWidth(),
                1 + texture.getTextureHeight());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(1, 1 + texture.getTextureHeight());

        GL11.glEnd();
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
    }

}
```

I really cant figure it out. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You enable texturing at the start of `drawTile()`:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

but never disable it again. This means that next time you call `displayBackground()`, the background will also be rendered using the texture of the last tile you rendered.

To fix this, add this call at the end of `drawTile()`:

```
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```